# ExpressJS Converting Timestamp to mm/dd/yyyy in Route

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, express

I am trying to convert my timestamp into mm/dd/yyyy format to be display on my index page and I have the function to do so, but I'm not sure how I should be calling it within my route to be used for display.

My current setup comes back with an error, `TypeError: Cannot call method 'getMonth' of undefined'`

route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var blogDB = require('../config/blogDB.js');
var Blogpost = require('./models/blogModel.js');
var paginate = require('express-paginate');

//index 
router.use(paginate.middleware(10, 50));


            function dateDisplayed(date){
                var dateCreated = (date.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear());
            }

    router.route('/') 


        // START GET method
        .get(function(req, res, next) {

            Blogpost.paginate({}, req.query.page, req.query.limit, function(err, pageCount, blogpost, itemCount) {




                if (err) return next(err)

                        if (err)
                            res.send(err);


                        blogpost.title = req.body.title; // get the blog title
                        blogpost.author = req.body.author; // get the author name
                        blogpost.tagline = req.body.tagline; // get tagline
                        blogpost.content = req.body.content; // get the blog content
                        blogpost.category = req.body.category; // get the category
                        blogpost.tags = req.body.tags; // get the tags
                        blogpost.date = dateDisplayed(req.body.date);






                        res.format({
                            html: function() {
                                res.render('pages/index', {
                                    blogpost: blogpost,
                                    pageCount: pageCount,
                                    itemCount: itemCount
                                })
                            },
                            json: function() {

                                res.json({
                                    object: 'blogpost',
                                    has_more: paginate.hasNextPages(req)(pageCount),
                                    data: blogpost
                                })
                            }
                        }); // END res.format(html, json)
            }); // END Blogpost.paginate
        }); // END GET method

router.route('/admin/posts/create')

    // START POST method
        .post(function(req, res) {

            console.log("New instance");

            var blogpost = new Blogpost(); // create a new instance of a Blogpost model

            blogpost.title = req.body.title; // set the blog title
            blogpost.blogUrl = blogpost.title.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g,"-");
            blogpost.author = req.body.author; // set the author name
            blogpost.tagline = req.body.tagline; // set the tagline
            blogpost.content = req.body.content; // set the blog content
            blogpost.category = req.body.category; // set the category
            blogpost.tags = req.body.tags; // set the tags
                //Save Blog Post
                blogpost.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);

                    res.redirect(303, '/'); //NEEDS TO BE CHANGED
                });

        }) // END POST method


        .get(function(req, res) {
            res.render('pages/blogpost-create');
        });

module.exports = router;
```

blogModel.js:

```
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');
var Schema      = mongoose.Schema;



var BlogPostSchema  = new Schema({
        title: String,
        blogUrl: String,
        author: String,
        tagline: String,
        category: String,
        content: String,
        tags: { type: String, lowercase: true },
        date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

BlogPostSchema.plugin( mongoosePaginate );

var Blogpost = mongoose.model("Blogpost", BlogPostSchema);



module.exports = mongoose.model('Blogpost', BlogPostSchema);
```

index.ejs:

```
<html>
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <% include ../partials/header %>
    </header>

    <div class="grid">
        <div class="col-9-12">
            <div class="blog-content">
                <% blogpost.forEach(function(blogpost) { %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><h2><a href="#" class="blog-title"><%= blogpost.title %></a></h2></td>
                        <td><h3><%= blogpost.date %></h3></td>
                        <td><h3 class="blog-category"><%= blogpost.category %></h3></td>
                        <td><h3 class="blog-tagline"><i><%= blogpost.tagline %></i></h3></td>
                        <td><p><%=: blogpost.content | truncate:800 | append:'...' %></p></td>
                        <td><a href="/blog/<%= blogpost.blogUrl %>" class="blog-read-more">Read More</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <% }); %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3-12">
            <div class="sidebar-personal-information">
                <div id="sidebar-social-media">
                    <ul id="sidebar-social-media-list">
                        <li><img class="sidebar-social-media-icons" src="images/linkedin.png"></li>
                        <li><img class="sidebar-social-media-icons" src="images/twitter.png"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="sidebar-current-titles">
                    <h3>Analytics Strategist</h3>
                    <h4><a href="#">Resolute Digital</a></h4>
                </div>
                <div id="sidebar-short-summary">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a massa ante. Vestibulum eu enim est. Curabitur a leo venenatis, semper tellus ac, venenatis nisi. Fusce magna urna, cursus quis egestas et, tincidunt ut nisi. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent congue nec lectus vel posuere.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar-newsletter-signup">
                <h3>NEWSLETTER</h3>
                <p>Sign up for my weekly newsletter</p>
                <form id="email-sign-up-form">
                    EMAIL: <input type="email" id="email-field" placeholder="johndoe@gmail.com"></input>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <input id="email-submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
            <% include ../partials/paginate %>
    </div>




    <footer>
        <% include ../partials/footer %>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.now` returns a Unix timestamp (number). If you want to use Date methods such as `getMonth()`, you have to create a Date object from your timestamp:

```
function dateDisplayed(timestamp) {
    var date = new Date(timestamp);
    return (date.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear());
}
```

Comment: Hey @Rodney Glope, thank you for your response. Right now I decided to go with your second options. I updated my date property in `blogModel.js` to `date: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }`. I then used your function and placed it in routes.js just before when I'm setting blogposts properties and set `                        blogpost.date = dateDisplayed(req.body.date);`. The issue is that when I log that object property I receive `NaN/NaN/NaN`

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I found the correct SchemaType for storing timestamps in Mongoose. Updated my answer. Just your function was the problem.

Comment: Hey @Rodney Golpe, sorry I'm a little confused from the change to your answer. These are my current changes:

blogModel: 

`date: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }`

routes.js

`function dateDisplayed(timestamp) {
                            var date = new Date(timestamp);
                            return (date.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear());
                        }`

and then `console.log(blogpost.date);` to check which is still appearing as `NaN/NaN/NaN`

Comment: Change `Date.now()` back to `Date.now`.

Comment: So still seeing that repsonse. Two questions related to this issue, 1) Do I need to use this function also with my `POST` method? 2) Since changing the SchemaType multiple times, would I only see this effect in my posts after my change?

Comment: Ha, well yeah -- if a BlogPost has already been stored with a bad value as the date, that value is getting passed to `dateDisplayed()`. One way to test whether this function will do what you want is force it to NOW if timestamp is invalid: `var date = new Date(timestamp || Date.now());`.

Comment: You do not use `dateDisplayed()` in your `POST` method because then the date would be stored as `11\04\2014` instead of as a timestamp. Your `BlogPost` model will insert the default date (`Date.now`) on `POST`.